# PHP $_SESSION variables randomly get overwritten?

Tags: php, html, session, variables

Okay, so when I run this script to remove a user's comment from a forum post, the $_SESSION['id'] (user's mysql id) changes to the $postid (the id of the forum post). I am not calling any function to set it, and I have `session_write_close();` called when the session is initialized.

```
<?php
session_start();

// I'm not showing connection code.
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){

    $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user']);
    $userid = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['id']);

    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    $postid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['article']);

    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `______`.`______` WHERE `userid`='$userid' AND `id`='$id' AND `user`='$user'")or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_affected_rows($result) == 1){

          mysql_query("UPDATE `_______`.`______` SET `points`=`points`-'1' WHERE `id`='$userid' AND `username`='$user'")or die(mysql_error());
          mysql_query("INSERT INTO `________`.`_______` (`user`,`userid`,`amount`,`reason`) VALUES('$user', '$userid', '-1', 'Removed a comment')")or die(mysql_error());

    }

    mysql_close($con);

    ob_start();
    header("location:../view-article?id=$postid");
    ob_end_flush();

} //if there is a user
else {

    ob_start();
    header("location:http://boundsblazer.com/not-logged-in?url=articles.view-article:id=$postid");
    ob_end_flush();
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you have other scripts or applications running which access similar variables? If so, set a different `session_name()` for each application so they don't accidentally interact.

Comment: Your problem is definitely somewhere else, there is nothing in this code that could do this...

Comment: Check if `register_globals` is activated? `echo ini_get('register_globals') ? 'On' : 'Off';`

Comment: But I don't understand how. Only this script causes the id to be changed.

Comment: `register_globals` was on... Why? Does that change anything? I didn't turn it on, btw...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `register_globals` is on, this line

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

possibly change the value of `$_SESSION['id']`. So please try again with `register_globals` off.

Comment: Worked. But why would they even add such a thing as `register_globals`?

Comment: @Ken Because some people are too lazy to take care of getting variables but just use $name right away which names are identical to sent body names.

Comment: register_globals is pretty much the top reason PHP has had such a miserable security reputation. Now that it defaults to off, the miserable rep is coming more from how often you see sql injection holes in PHP code.